# How to I apply dash bootstrap theme to a slider?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to apply the bootstrap theme slider to the dash slider and it does not change in appearance.

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import dcc, HTML

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
app.layout =  html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Label("RangeSlider", html_for="range-slider"),
        dcc.RangeSlider(id="range-slider", min=0, max=10, value=[3, 7]),
    ],
    className="mb-3",
)
if _name_ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

This shows the plain slider and not the slider you see in the theme example https://bootswatch.com/lux/?optionsRadios=option1 Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not run, for several reasons ... this one runs:

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import dcc, html

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
app.layout =  html.Div(
[
    dbc.Label("RangeSlider", html_for="range-slider"),
    dcc.RangeSlider(id="range-slider", min=0, max=10, value=[3, 7]),
],
className="mb-3",
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

[slider looks like this on my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbfha.png)

What exactly should it look like? Your link does not help me understanding what you want it to look like.

Comment: I want it to look like the sliders from the Form section in the Bootstrap theme example. https://imgur.com/a/CkrUaWf